# StringBuilder exception on changing Capacity!

Tags: c#, .net, exception, memory, stringbuilder

here is my code line:

```
StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
myCompleteMessage.Capacity = Int32.MaxValue-1;
```

tryed that also:

```
myCompleteMessage.Capacity = myCompleteMessage.MaxCapacity-1;
```

I get exception on line 2.

```
Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.
```

Stack Trace:

```
at System.String.GetStringForStringBuilder(String value, Int32 startIndex, Int32 length, Int32 capacity)
at System.Text.StringBuilder.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
at Orca.Server.HandleClientComm(Object newClient) in C:\Users\Dan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\msig\Orca\Server.cs:line 100
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(Object obj)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to specify that as capacity? It usually works best if you let framework to handle capacity (unless you know exactly how many you need).

Comment: If you require such a big string you need to revisit the design but the question is good.

Comment: What's "Preforming by design" means?

Comment: It fails in x64 as well.

Comment: @Danpe Are you saying you can't get a StringBuilder to grow above 2048 characters without setting the Capacity? If so, that seems odd. Maybe post another question asking why you're having that problem with StringBuilder?

Comment: I suspect Danpe's problem is with a poorly chosen solution to a different problem that they could get better help on if it was asked. Probably one better solved by output to a file.

Comment: I think Danpe's 2048 is "about 2GB", not 2048... but it is just guess. 2048 feels more like a bug in code that uses the StringBuilder...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are on a 32bit system, that second line will always fail. You're asking .NET to allocate 4 GB of space to your StringBuilder, which is more memory than the process has to work with (thanks to Joel for pointing out char takes up 2 bytes, not 1).

**EDIT**
If you take a look at `StringBuilder` with ILSpy, you see this bit of code in the set for `Capacity`:

```
if (this.Capacity != value)
{
    int num = value - this.m_ChunkOffset;
    char[] array = new char[num];
    Array.Copy(this.m_ChunkChars, array, this.m_ChunkLength);
    this.m_ChunkChars = array;
}
```

By setting Capacity to int.MaxValue - 1, you're telling .NET to try and allocate a 4 GB char array, which is why the code is failing.

Comment: Hmm fails on x64 too. Is there a way to specify a larger process space? Why would the default MaxCapacity be Int.MaxValue if it doesn't support it?

Comment: Just curious :) Not questioning the logic

Comment: You right.
`myCompleteMessage.MaxCapacity/2` WRONG!
`myCompleteMessage.MaxCapacity/4` RIGHT!

Comment: are you compiling for x64 in your test?

Comment: Don't forget that `char` is 16-bit Unicode. A Capacity of 1000 is 2000 bytes. @Adam, `int.MaxValue` is the only sensible answer because `Capacity` is `int`. Any lesser `MaxCapacity` would be unnecessarily arbitrary, as the class is limited by memory anyway. If you had a machine with 6-8GB of memory or more, I'm sure you could set `Capacity` to `MaxCapacity` just fine, as it would probably use 4GB.

Comment: @Joel Thanks for pointing that out about char being unicode. I updated my answer.

Comment: @Joel I actually have a machine wih 16GB RAM :)
i compile it in a 64bit workspace with but maybe because it's set to "Any CPU" in the properties :)

Comment: @Danpe: **Any CPU** just lets you create an assembly that will run 32-bit on 32-bit OS and 64-bit on 64-bit OS (chosen by the JIT compiler). And as Alexei points out in his answer, the CLR imposes its own limit on the size of objects, so the second half of my previous comment is incorrect anyway. It would need to be contiguous memory, which is yet another complication.

Answer (score 2):

CLR heap is limited to 2GB objects ( http://blogs.msdn.com/b/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx - for 2.0, I believe it the same for 4.0) so there is nothing that can allocate one continious block of memory above that size. For characters it gives you about Int.MaxValue/2 entries.

If you really need to manage such amount of text check out alternative implementations of MemoryStream that allow chunking or arrays that allow chuncking. If you want to stay within default classes - consider writing data to temporary file (temporary file created with DeleteOnClose may not be even commited to disk - so you get better performance compared to StringBuilder or MemoryStream that have to copy data on each increase in capacity - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileoptions.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

StringBuilder's Capacity property is the number of characters to set aside as the string buffer.  With UTF-8, a character can be up to 4 bytes.  Even at 2 bytes, a capacity of `Int32.MaxValue - 1` is well over capacity for a 32-bit system, weighing in at 4 GB for just 2-byte characters (UTF-8/ASCII).  Also, StringBuilder's default Capacity is already set to Int32.MaxValue if you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.maxcapacity.aspx).

If you are looping to fill the StringBuilder, you may be filling it faster than .NET can clean up allocated memory through garbage collection, which is why it may be stopping at the 2048 character length.  Also, internally it needs a contiguous block of memory, which it also may be running into an issue with.

Your question, though, is about the Capacity property, and you'll never be able to allocate that much capacity on a 32-bit system.  I found an [interesting discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvb/thread/968ce154-0cfc-4d57-98f7-61c9886cefd4) on MSDN dealing with this specific problem and through testing it was found that actual capacity is a great deal lower since Int32.MaxValue capacity translates to 4 GB of storage necessary when all characters are 2-bytes.

Can you use a [Memory-Mapped file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx) instead?  StringBuilder's were not meant for this and you need to reconsider your design.